# automatic backup

Tags: backup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to get database backup automatically](https://serverfault.com/questions/305721/how-to-get-database-backup-automatically)

i want to have automatic backup in my program.it means that for example every 30 minutes a table that contains backup schedules should be checked and get backup from my db if the special time in the schedule is passed.this backup code should work even if the program is not running,means that it should starts when the windows loads and stops when the windows shuts down.
now i want to know what is the best way for this? can windows service do this for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write it as a service or just call it from the Windows Scheduler. Either approach will work, with the possible advantage going to the scheduler route as the scheduling is also taken care of with that approach.

Comment: thanks for reply, but what is Windows Scheduler.by the way i used windows service but i need to use Timer control in it to check the backup schedule table every 30 minutes but it does not work in windows service.

Comment: http://www.iopus.com/guides/winscheduler.htm - it might vary slightly across the different versions of Windows.

Comment: thanks but i want to do it programmaticaly not by wizard.

Comment: The wizard is strictly for the scheduling of a task, which in this case is something you would program (the actual backup task).